# How to I stop this Netbeans IDE highlighting?

Tags: html, netbeans, ide

I am currently using Netbeans IDE 7.4 to write some basic HTML code.  Whenever I type a tag, it immediately highlights it, making it next to impossible to read until I click somewhere else.  This is incredibly annoying.  I have looked at all previous solutions, but for some reason they only work with Java and not HTML.  Does anybody know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Seems like a different color scheme would help.

Comment: I would prefer if there was just a way to permanently turn off the highlighting, but if a different color scheme is the only option, I'll just go for that.  Thank you.

Comment: This only seems to work with Java, I can't do it when I am working with HTML... Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Then try it with the HTML Syntax option (if there is one).  The one that I posted below uses the Java Code option.

Comment: I did try it with the HTML Syntax option.  But there is no "mark occurrences" option like there is with the Java syntax option.

Answer (score 2):

After ongoing bouts of frustration with the **NetBeans highlighting**, I finally figured out this was not so much of an issue of *highlighting being turned on or off*, but more an issue of *how the highlighting is being rendered.*

Turning highlighting off completely (as suggested above) has never been fully successful in my case in either NetBeans 8.x or 9.0 (I'm currently using 9.0), and the highlighting can seriously become so annoying in that it's too difficult to read the highlighted text, that it becomes a distraction and negatively impacts productivity.

Having determined that this is a question of *rendering* verses IDE *functionality*, the original answer is on target as far as modifying the Mark Occurrences styling in:

Tools > Options > Fonts & Colors > Syntax -> Mark Occurrences.

However, since I work in multiple projects of multiple types, I selected 'All Languages' in the drop-down, set the foreground and background colors to 'Inherited' (getting rid of the sickly yellow background (I'm using the Sublime Theme) and added Bold and Italic styling to the inherited font setting.

Now, no matter the project or the language, highlighting is still working as intended, but it's no longer an annoyance.

Hope this helps for others who have been likewise frustrated by this feature of NetBeans! It was getting to the point of almost driving me to another IDE.

Comment: I have login to SOF only to voteup this answer. Unconfigured Netbeans is terrible.

Answer (score 1):

In Netbeans 12.5, this is configurable in Tools|Options|Editor tab|Highlighting tab under Editor tab

Answer (score 0):

> The mark-occurrences color can be modified in Options->Fonts & Colors
>   ->  Syntax, language: Java, Category: Mark Occurrences.  To turn it off completely go to Options->Java code -> Mark Occurrences  and
>   disable the first checkbox.

http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/Turn-off-or-change-the-automatic-highlight-of-the-mark-occurrence-feature-td2949743.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to change profile. That works for me.

```
Tools > Options > Fonts & Colors > profile.
```

Hope it will help.